# Any() is not working in Brightstardb

Tags: c#, brightstardb

I have a document like this:

```
    {
       "Document":{
                  "Principles":[{"text":"Text","history":["Text1","Text2","Text3"]}]
                  }
    }
```

I would like to search for all Principles that contain a history that contains "Text".

I have 2 interfaces like this :

```
[Entity]
public interface IDocument
{
   string Id{get;}

   ICollection<IPrinciple> Principles{get;set;}
}

[Entity]
public interface IPrinciple
{
   string Id{get;}

   ICollection<string> history{get;set;}

   string text{get;set;}
}
```

Here's what I did :

```
using(var context=new MyEntityContext(connectionString))
{
     var principles=(from p in context.Principles where p.history.Any(h=>h.Contains("Text")) select p).ToList();
}
```

But I am getting a list that contains no principle.

Comment: At least put valid json if you want some help.

Comment: It's a sample json document. I had some typo but I don't think that it's relevant to the question itself. I would correct it.

Comment: It is relevant if you want someone to reproduce your problem

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at `context.Principles` and see if it returns any objects, and whether those objects contain expected data? I think it's not wise start the question with "Any() is not working" because there is zero chance that the problem is in the Any() function.

Comment: Yes the problem is not in Any. I re create your code and there is no problem.

Comment: Here you can check it :https://dotnetfiddle.net/pZPKNv

Comment: @mybirthname I am using brightstardb to store my documents.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Yes I have checked that I am getting all Principles if I omit the Any part  I also can search Principles using its text property without any problem.

Comment: Are you using a Ling provider specifically for brightstardb?  If so I'd suggest that you determine the SQL, or I guess in this case NoSql that your linq query is transformed into to help determine the issue.  Usually you can do that by calling `ToString` on the query (before calling `ToList` on it).

Comment: @juharr brightstardb offers its own Linq provider out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write it this way :

```
 var principles= _context.Principles.Any(p => p.history.Contains("Text"));
```

You will get the following error :

> NotSupportedException : LINQ-to-SPARQL does not currently support the
>   result operator 'Any()'

So your guess was right, currently brightstarDB doesn't seems to support the Any() operation.

You always can replace your Any with a Where and some tweaks to obtain a similar (but working) result

Comment: I have solved the problem somehow by converting history from string into IHistory. I will post my solution as an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Any() is the problem. This program works just fine, returning the expected 2 principles from the query. I'm just using the IPrinciple and IDocument interfaces exactly as you posted in your original question, and the query is also exactly as you posted originally.

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = "type=embedded;storesDirectory=brightstardb;storeName=anytest";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetupStore();
        QueryStore();
    }

    private static void SetupStore()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists("brightstardb"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("brightstardb");
            using (var context = new MyEntityContext(ConnectionString)
            )
            {
                var doc1 = context.Documents.Create();
                var doc2 = context.Documents.Create();
                var doc3 = context.Documents.Create();
                var p1 = context.Principles.Create();
                p1.History = new List<string> {"Strings", "of", "Text"};
                var p2 = context.Principles.Create();
                p2.History = new List<string> {"Nothing", "To See Here", "Move Along"};
                var p3 = context.Principles.Create();
                p3.History = new List<string> { "Another", "Principle containing Text"};
                doc1.Principles = new List<IPrinciple> {p1};
                doc2.Principles = new List<IPrinciple> {p2};
                doc3.Principles = new List<IPrinciple> {p3};
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void QueryStore()
    {
        using (var context = new MyEntityContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            var principles = (from p in context.Principles where p.History.Any(h => h.Contains("Text")) select p).ToList();
            foreach (var p in principles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found principle: {0}", p.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```